# Get custom attribute of gRPC method (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, attributes, grpc

I have a simple custom attribute `AuthorizedUser` which is attached to a **gRPC** method as below:

```
[AuthorizedUser]
public override Task<ServerStatusReply> ServerStatus(ServerStatusRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
{
    // ...
    // some logic to create a response object, irrelevant for the question
    // ...
    return Task.FromResult(response);
}
```

Then, I created an interceptor for unary calls which intercepts this method:

```
public override async Task<TResponse> UnaryServerHandler<TRequest, TResponse>(
    TRequest request,
    ServerCallContext context,
    UnaryServerMethod<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
{
    // ??? - how do I get my custom attribute of the method?

    try
    {
        return await continuation(request, context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Note: The gRPC framework also logs exceptions thrown by handlers to .NET Core logging.
        _logger.LogError(ex, $"Error thrown by {context.Method}.");
        throw;
    }
}
```

All works perfectly, but here's the question - how do I know which method was intercepted and what attributes it has attached to it?

The best I can find inside the `request`, `context` and `continuation` objects are proto name of the method, rather than actual C# method ID with a correct namespace.

I want to know the method to be able to get a list of all attributes attached to that method to execute additional custom logic.

Comment: As you state: this information is not exposed to the interceptor API. I *can* think of a way to do this using a custom server binder, but: that wouldn't work for regular gRPC stubs since the gRPC binder will be detected. IMO you might want to open a ticket on the GitHub repo, so it can be considered at the API level. Note also that IIRC aspnet attributes are still observed and processed

Comment: Hm, I see. That's unfortunate to hear. Maybe there is some other way to decorate the method to pass that information into the interceptor? As for the API suggestion - good point, I will open an issue on their repo.

Comment: Not sure it's doable. Try to use `IHttpContextAccessor` to retrieve the current `HttpContext`, then retrieve the endpoint with `context.GetEndpoint()`. Maybe there is something useful in the endpoint's metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the attribute from the endpoint metadata

```cs
var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();
var endpoint = httpContext.GetEndpoint();
var metadata = endpoint?.Metadata.GetMetadata<GrpcMethodMetadata>();
var attribute = metadata?.ServiceType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuthorizedUser), inherit: false);
```

Comment: Hello the above custom attribute you get, refers to service type not to the method.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Artur solution, this should work:

```
var metadata = context.GetHttpContext()
   .GetEndpoint()
   .Metadata
   .GetMetadata<AuthorizedUser>();
```

If the attribute exists then `metadata` should not be null.

We assume that your attibute is declared as `AuthorizedUser` and not as `AuthorizedUserAttribute`.